# Select all the elements of the last row of a grid with a responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

I've created a grid of elements using grid, and every elements from a row is separated with a bottom border. I would like to remove this border bottom line for all the elements from the last row.
This grid displays 6 elements at first but once I click on a view more button it displays 15 elements

I've used media query to find the breakpoints and used nth-last-child to make it responsive like this:

```
.grid-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

@media (min-width: 540px) {
  .grid-item:nth-last-child(-n + 2) {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 920px) {
  .grid-item:nth-last-child(-n + 3) {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
```

And it works the way I want except when I click on the view more button and then, between 540px and 920px, the number of elements of the last row is not 2 but only one, and so it selects an elements of the last row as well because it takes the two last elements. I wants to prevent this behavior and only select the elements of the last row

Comment: Please provide html with your question for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple, if somewhat hacky, way might be to put a top border on each item and cover-up the ones from the top row with a pseudo element.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid: grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  position: relative;
}

.grid::after {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;/* note slightly taller than the borders to compensate for 'rounding errors' */
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}

.grid>* {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  background: cyan;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```